# Facebook App - Browsing Random Posts

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I've been tearing through the Facebook API documentation and beginner-level tutorials on the basics of an in-Facebook app and am starting to get a grasp of the basics. I'm looking to develop an app for a semester-long project for school and was wondering if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction of what documentation/tutorials to look for. To give some further context, here is the basic idea behind the app:

It will allow users to fill out basic drop-down form filters (Friends lists, date ranges, post types, etc.) and then press a button to 'stumble' to a random existing post (i.e. a random picture from 2 years ago, a random status or wall post from 3 months ago, etc.)

I was thinking of maybe looking further into FQL, but would just like to get some advice before proceeding.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have yet to find a way to do a stem search via the Graph other than from the http://graph.facebook.com/search? link.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ and look for the search section.

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely a step in the right direction. Let me know if you figure out any way to do a stem search or at least emulate something like it.

Comment: I know other people have looked for it too, but have been unsuccessful in finding a stem search via FQL